# SWIFT 3. BezierPath and update View

Tags: ios

I am sorry asking such a question, but I am lost now after reading sooo many blogs on how to possibly solving my issue.
I have added  a new view to my storyboard "CircleView" which has the CircleClock class assigned. 
The first what I am doing is calling the initializer of CircleClock.
Then followed by the slider changing the arc width and if changed setNeedsDisplay() is called. The circle is drawn initially, but the 
slider change does not call the function draw(_ rect: CGRect) again.
Also what I have recognized is that the values set in

```
init(origin: CGPoint) {
self.startAngle = 5
self.endAngle = 6
```

are not set to 5 and 6 after init is done , they are back to the original values, like 
var endAngle : CGFloat = 3.14 / 4.
I saw a lot of comments of adding circle as a subview. Which I tried, but then I have two views shown and the new added subview is getting the updates from the slider the original still does not change. But the values for the angles 5 and 6 are set now!??

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var circle = CircleClock(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
@IBAction func sliderWidth(_ sender: Any) {
    circle.arcWidth = CGFloat(sliderWidth.value)
    // so my slider is changing the arcWitdh
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didTap(_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGR)
   // view.addSubview(circle) // This will be the question
 }




class CircleClock: UIView {
let size: CGFloat = 150.0

var arcWidth: CGFloat = 76{
    didSet {
        // if changed please redraw
        print("\(arcWidth)")
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

let π:CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI)
var path = UIBezierPath()
var mycenter = CGPoint()
var radius = CGFloat()
var startAngle = CGFloat() // = 3 * 3.14 / 4
var endAngle : CGFloat = 3.14 / 4

init(origin: CGPoint) {
self.startAngle = 5
self.endAngle = 6
super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 100.0, y: 0.0, width: size, height:  size))
}
function draw

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
print("width: \(self.bounds.width)")
print("width: \(self.bounds.height)")
…
```

[image: twoarcs]